# Unresolved external symbol referenced in class template constructor (in VS 2008)

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

The following MWE fails to compile in VS 2008

Bar.h

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar();
};
```

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar()
{
}
```

Foo.h

```
#include "Bar.h"

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
    }

private:
    Bar m_bar;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Bar::Bar(void)" (??0Bar@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Foo<int>::Foo<int>(void)" (??0?$Foo@H@@QAE@XZ)
```

However the same code *successfully* compiles in GCC 3.4.4 -- old compiler I know, but its currently the latest version that I've got on my machine. Is this code standard compliant or is this a VS 2008 bug?

Comment: Stupid question, but are you sure you added `Bar.cpp` to the project?

Comment: Don't forget your include guards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `Bar.cpp` is also compiled and linked, the code is completely correct and this is a VC++-Bug. Check whether you've set up the project properly.